# List returning null after adding item

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm adding item to the list but when I return the list it's empty, not sure what's happening. Observing this behavior after migrating from net core 2.2 to 3.1.

It works if I remove `(string guid, string type)` in `List`

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetLatestProducts()
{
    var httpResp = new List<(LatestProducts.RootObject, string guid, string type)>();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "p_spring-cloud-services/releases/latest");
    var response = await _client_deployed_prod_update.SendAsync(request);
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    LatestProducts.RootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LatestProducts.RootObject>(json);

    if (model != null)
    {
        httpResp.Add((model, "p_spring-cloud-services-9f414709158c9309f5e3", "p_spring-cloud-services"));
    }

    return Ok(httpResp);
}
```

Class:

```
public class LatestProducts
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Version version { get; set; }
        public string release_type { get; set; }
        public string release_date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The response I'm getting from the request:

```
{
  "id": 558725,
  "version": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 1,
    "build": 5,
    "revision": -1,
    "majorRevision": -1,
    "minorRevision": -1
  },
  "release_type": "Maintenance Release",
  "release_date": "2020-01-22"
}
```

What I want the list to look like:

```
{
  "id": 558725,
  "version": {
    "major": 3,
    "minor": 1,
    "build": 5,
    "revision": -1,
    "majorRevision": -1,
    "minorRevision": -1
  },
  "release_type": "Maintenance Release",
  "release_date": "2020-01-22",
}
"guid": "p_spring-cloud-services-9f414709158c9309f5e3", 
"type": "p_spring-cloud-services"
```

Comment: What are you expecting the response data would look like?

Comment: Why is `LatestProducts` a class?  It looks like it should be a namespace.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Amy it is under namespace I just did not mention it here.

Comment: @CaiusJard I updated the question

Comment: @Jawad yes I'm aware of it.

Comment: Your list parameters are wrong. Create a class to hold these properties `LatestProducts.RootObject, string guid, string type)` then .add(on that list with the new object ). That's not how you use a list. `List<myClass>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather, you are trying to add two more properties to the class that takes in the data from your json. Issue is, you cant have a json with value only, you need the key as well. Following process uses the key: "request" for the model when its added to the Response object.

You can have two separate classes, one for your model and one for your response. Similar to this where you have **RootObject** that contains your model and a **Response**

```
    public class Version
    {
        public int major { get; set; }
        public int minor { get; set; }
        public int build { get; set; }
        public int revision { get; set; }
        public int majorRevision { get; set; }
        public int minorRevision { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Version version { get; set; }
        public string release_type { get; set; }
        public string release_date { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public RootObject request { get; set; }
        public string guid { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
```

and use these classes like this in the main,

```
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    var httpResp = new Response
    {
        guid = "p_guid",
        type = "p_type",
        request = model
    };
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(httpResp, Formatting.Indented));
```

**Output**

Above produces the following json:

```
{
  "request": {
    "id": 558725,
    "version": {
      "major": 3,
      "minor": 1,
      "build": 5,
      "revision": -1,
      "majorRevision": -1,
      "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "release_type": "Maintenance Release",
    "release_date": "2020-01-22"
  },
  "guid": "p_guid",
  "type": "p_type"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna struggle to get a `List<(object, string,string)>` to produce the output you want, if it serializes, because you've said you want the output JSON to have names of `guid` and `type` for the strings but nowhere is this information in your code

Perhaps ditch the list (your desired output doesn't contain a collection) and try using an anonymous class:

```
return Ok(new { 
  model=model, 
  guid = "p_spring-cloud-services-9f414709158c9309f5e3", 
  type = "p_spring-cloud-services" 
});
```

Bear in mind that your model data will end up introduced with a name of `model` - I'm not sure you'll ever succeed in getting the exact output you specified because it doesn't appear to be valid Json (no opening brace, model data has no name, trailing comma after release date, missing comma after close model bracket, missing close bracket at EOF). This is what I'd expect my suggestion to produce:

```
{
"model": {
    "id": 558725,
    "version": {
        "major": 3,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": 5,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "release_type": "Maintenance Release",
    "release_date": "2020-01-22"
},
"guid": "p_spring-cloud-services-9f414709158c9309f5e3",
"type": "p_spring-cloud-services"
}
```

If you want the `"model":` to be something else, call it some other name in the anonymous object, on the left hand side of model=model